# Python3 and Tkinter, I can not get radio buttons to change value of a variable.

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

trying to write a program to move mouse with the keyboard and record locations on gui buttons on my screen. i'm using a variable named speed as way to move the mouse across the screen faster.  why can't i get the  variable speed to changed when I select the different radio buttons? Thanks for your help

```
import pyautogui, readchar
from tkinter.ttk import *
import tkinter as tk
import time

#rootsetup  
root=tk.Tk()
root.title("GUI Mapping Tool")
root.geometry('650x200')
CurrentPostionX, CurrentPostionY=  pyautogui.position()

#Circle or Rectangle radio
Circle = Radiobutton(root,text='Circle', value=101)
Rectangle = Radiobutton(root,text='Rectangle', value=102)
Circle.grid(column=4, row=1)
Rectangle.grid(column=3, row=1)
#Speed radio
speedchoice=tk.IntVar()       
def selected():

  if speedchoice.get()==1:
        Speed=1
        print("1")
  if speedchoice.get()==10:
        Speed=10
        print("10")
  if speedchoice.get()==25:
        Speed=25
        print("25")
  if speedchoice.get()==100:
        Speed=100
        print("100")
Speed1 = Radiobutton(root,text='1x', value=1 , command=selected, variable= speedchoice) 

Speed10 = Radiobutton(root,text='10x', value=10,  command=selected, variable= speedchoice )

Speed25 = Radiobutton(root, text='25x', value=25,  command=selected, variable= speedchoice )

Speed100 = Radiobutton(root,text='100x', value=100, command=selected, variable= speedchoice )

Speed1.grid(column=4, row=0)

Speed10.grid(column=5, row=0)

Speed25.grid(column=6, row=0)

Speed100.grid(column=7, row=0)


#MoveMouseWithArrows:
def key(event):

    CurrentPostionX, CurrentPostionY=  pyautogui.position()


    Direction=event.keysym
     if Direction=='Up':
        pyautogui.moveTo(CurrentPostionX, CurrentPostionY-1*Speed)      
     if event.keysym =='Down':
        pyautogui.moveTo(CurrentPostionX, CurrentPostionY+1*Speed)
     if event.keysym =='Left':
        pyautogui.moveTo(CurrentPostionX-1*Speed, CurrentPostionY)
     if event.keysym =='Right':
        pyautogui.moveTo(CurrentPostionX+1*Speed, CurrentPostionY)
root.bind_all('<Key>', key)
# Locations Name Entry
txt = Entry(root,width=20)
txt.grid(column=3, row=0)
CurrentPostionX, CurrentPostionY=  pyautogui.position()
Xpos=tk.StringVar()
Ypos=tk.StringVar()
def update_label():

   while 1>0:
      CurrentPostionX, CurrentPostionY=  pyautogui.position()
      Xpos.set(str(CurrentPostionX))
      Ypos.set(str(CurrentPostionY))
      root.update()
Xaxislabel=tk.Label(root, text= "X:", font=("Arial Bold", 50))
Xaxislabel.grid(column=0, row=0)
Xposlabel=tk.Label(root,textvariable=Xpos, font=("Arial Bold", 50))
Xposlabel.grid(column=1, row=0)
Yaxislabel=tk.Label(root, text= "Y:", font=("Arial Bold", 50))
Yaxislabel.grid(column=0, row=1)
Yposlabel=tk.Label(root,textvariable=Ypos, font=("Arial Bold", 50))
Yposlabel.grid(column=1, row=1)
update_label()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Forget the `Speed` variable and the entire `selected` function. Just use `speedchoice` directly: `pyautogui.moveTo(CurrentPostionX, CurrentPostionY-1*speedchoice.get())`

Comment: BTW, the problem is due to the function having it's own scope, which is something python courses cover in the first week. You need to go back to python basics, and work through a couple beginner tutorials. You might find beginner forums like learnpython.reddit.com helpful.